# MessageBox Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox, information-retrieval

Isn't there a quick way to display a 'Show Information' button in a simple `Windows.Forms.MessageBox`?

I would like to give the user the option to view the `stack trace` when error is occurs, but sometimes it shows a long result and makes the message window messy.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show("exception " + ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` has several overloads, one takes a Buttons enum.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not.
Create an own form OR have a look at the [WindowsAPICodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack), great stuff there.

Answer (score 0):

No. it is not possible.
The standard MessageBox support only: Yes, No,Cancel, Retry and OK Buttons.

But you can write your own MessageBox form class and use it instead.

Or you can do a Messagebox with  YesNo buttonas and in the message a write question "Want to see more information?"  and when the  user presses Yes, you show him another window with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I would (and have) display the first 200 chars of the stacktrace and then allow them to download a text file with the full stacktrace if the choose.

Code Sample below:

```
// C#
//Display frmAbout as a modal dialog
Form frmAbout = new Form();
frmAbout.ShowDialog();
```

You can do some really nice things if you dedicate a form to it, like "Send error to me" - email button, etc.

Comment: As a separate modal form.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do it , but you can use benefit from yesno buttons by asking users : Do you want to view the exceptions? . If user click yes , it shows the exception , If user click no , it just close the messegebox.

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 { 
   DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Exception catched , would you like to view the exception?", "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
   if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
     MessageBox.Show("exception " + ex.StackTrace);
   }
 }
```

Hope it works and sorry for any mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could use exception message box.

```
 try
 {
   // Do something that may generate an exception.
    throw new ApplicationException("An error has occured");
 }
 catch (ApplicationException ex)
 {
    // Define a new top-level error message.
    string str = "The action failed.";
    // Add the new top-level message to the handled exception.
    ApplicationException exTop = new ApplicationException(str, ex);
    exTop.Source = this.Text;
    // Show an exception message box with an OK button (the default).
    ExceptionMessageBox box = new ExceptionMessageBox(exTop);
    box.Show(this);
 }
```

you can refer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166340.aspx